# Can an iPhone 12 Pro possibly survive in 5m / 16ft deep lake-water for 24 hours?

Tags: iphone, waterproof

So yesterday night I dropped my new phone in a lake... We couldn't go after it at the time because it was too deep and too dark.

I want to hire a diver if there is any chance that my phone is still working by now, but it's hard for me to figure out how (un)likely that actually is. I know the specifications say 30 Minutes in 2m deep water but I can imagine that the actual ability of the phone to stay underwater could be much better in some cases.

Comment: If it is rated for 30 min at 2 meters, 24 hours at 5 meters seems to be way out of any safety limits. How expensive is the diver, how expensive is a new phone?

Comment: the phones value is more then ten times what diving after it would cost me...

Comment: Is the value because of data that is not backed up?

Comment: Well, for a factor 10 it seems to make sense to send a diver and hope for the best.

Answer (score 1):

Yes hire a diver. The actual performance is designed to be better than the specifications, but drops and falls could allow cracks that make it soaked in minutes at 10cm.

Depending how air is trapped it could be just fine undisturbed for a day or three. You also can get data off a phone that isn’t safe to charge or run - don’t mess with rice and get it immediately to a recovery specialist if the value is in the data or continued operation of the device.